# cPanel auto deployment using git has stuck in loop

Tags: git, yaml, hosting, cpanel

I used the git version from cPanel to deploy directly from Github repo. I have added the .cpanel.yml file to automatically copy the folders into the /public_html folder.

But now for some reason, the deployment has stuck in an infinite loop and it is using up all the resources like I/O usage.

Can someone please provide help with this matter? I cannot even delete the repo from the list as it is in progress. I tried deleting the repo folder from /repositories/ but it also did not make any change.

It has stuck on some previous commit.

The .cpanel.yml file was as follows:

```
---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/user/public_html/
    - /bin/cp /. $DEPLOYPATH
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your deployment got stuck but this is how I usually do it:

```
---
deployment:
  tasks:
       - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/user/public-html/
       - /bin/cp -R * $DEPLOYPATH
```